# sabre api generating token using laravel

Tags: api, laravel-5, sabre

I am going to integrate sabre soap api with laravel, the first step is to generate token can somebody please suggest, what strategy to be used to call sabre api for token. As i plan to use GuzzleHttp\Client for api call but don't how to setup.

```
 public function getApi($method,$body='')
    {


try {


 $client = new GuzzleClient();

            $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <eb:MessageHeader eb:version="1">
            <eb:From>
                <eb:PartyId>Client</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:From>
            <eb:To>
                <eb:PartyId>SWS</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:To>
            <eb:CPAId>'.base64_encode('8cpd').'</eb:CPAId>
            <eb:ConversationId>1234</eb:ConversationId>
            <eb:Service>Session</eb:Service>
            <eb:Action>TokenCreateRQ</eb:Action>
            <eb:MessageData>
                <eb:MessageId>1234</eb:MessageId>
                <eb:Timestamp>2015-01-01T00:00:00</eb:Timestamp>
            </eb:MessageData>
        </eb:MessageHeader>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>'.base64_encode($this->username).'</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password>'.base64_encode($this->password).'</wsse:Password>
               <Organization>'.base64_encode('8cpd').'</Organization>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <sws:TokenCreateRQ Version="1.0.0" />
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';

            $request = $client->post('https://api.test.sabre.com/v2/auth/token', [
              'body' => [
                'xml' => $xml
              ]
            ]);



            $xml = simplexml_load_string($request->getBody());
            return json_encode($xml);

        } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {

            dd($e);
            return $e;
        }
```

Comment: This question is too broad. Please show us what you have tried already.

Comment: i added some code which i tried..

Comment: You are trying to do a REST service call sending XML. You must do one or the other

Comment: thanks, can you please put me in the right direction i want to use soap